# How do I take advantage of PartialView, AJAX, and model validation attributes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, partial-views

I am new to MVC and trying to get my head around AJAX calls and model validation. Here's what I have:

A Controller action that serves a View with a single textbox and a link. The View looks like:

```
<div> 
... 
<input type="text" name="registration" value=""/><a id="checkRegoLink" href="#">Check rego</> 
... 
</div>
```

The checkRegoLink does an $.ajax() POST call to an action, which serves a PartialViewResult.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"/Entry/CheckRego",
  type: "POST",
  data: {...stuff...},
  success: function (data, status, request){
    $("#target").html(data);
  },
});
```

The PartialViewResult serves a strongly-typed partial view `_CreateEntry`. The model for that view has some `[Required]` attributes for various properties. Here's some snippet of this partial view:

```
@model namespace.EntryModel
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEntry", "Entry", FormMethod.Post))
{
 ...various entry fields, labels and stuff...
 <input type="submit" value="Add Entry"/>
}
```

My question is, how do I return that partial view back into the `$("#target")` div complete with validation error messages. In the controller action that accepts the POST from the strongly-typed view I have tried `return PartialView("_CreateEntry",model)` - but that returns the partialview itself, complete with validation error messages, but of course on its own, without the parent layout.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I am slowly getting better with voting up and accepting answers. Please excuse my low stats - I will definitely vote up answers and accept them as I go.

Thanks,
Dany.

PS.
I am using MVC 3 latest RC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Ajax.BeginForm() instead of Html.BeginForm(). Look at the usage, it should allow you to specify different options, including the div to update. Unless you have reasons for doing it manually, why manually do whats already built in?

Edit:

You say "My question is, how do I return that partial view back into the $("#target") div complete with validation error messages."

Then you say "... but that returns the partialview itself, complete with validation error messages, but of course on its own, without the parent layout." <-- isn't this exactly what you want?

Isn't that what you want? The partialview complete with validation error messages?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct - I had a bit of a brain blockage earlier. I will eventually have a look at Ajax.BeginForm() but for now I have managed to wire it up manually with $.ajax() jquery call. One question though - if I use Ajax.BeginForm() inside the partial view can I target a div outside it, ie. in the parent view?

Comment: Unsure on that one - try it out.